# extract part of a paragraph in using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string

i have the following paragraph:

Free Daily Horoscope by findyourfate.comhttp://www.findyourfate.comThings are good and getting better -- and you need to learn how to accept this fact. While this may sound like flippant or sarcastic advice, the truth is that lately, whenever the fates have thrown a few rose petals in your path, you have chosen to see them as just more debris -- if you have elected to see them at all. Wake up and wise up. You need to start acknowledging the gifts as gifts meant for you. You need to understand just how worthy of them you are.http://www.findyourfate.com/rss/dailyhoroscope-feed.asp?sign=Aries [return delivery report]

which I stored in a string using vb.net.

How can I split that string to output only the following part:

Things are good and getting better -- and you need to learn how to accept this fact. While this may sound like flippant or sarcastic advice, the truth is that lately, whenever the fates have thrown a few rose petals in your path, you have chosen to see them as just more debris -- if you have elected to see them at all. Wake up and wise up. You need to start acknowledging the gifts as gifts meant for you. You need to understand just how worthy of them you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you have this same paragraph and each time you need to get same output you can use replace instead of split it's easier:

```
 Dim texts As String = "Free Daily Horoscope by findyourfate.comhttp://www.findyourfate.comThings are good and getting better -- and you need to learn how to accept this fact. While this may sound like flippant or sarcastic advice, the truth is that lately, whenever the fates have thrown a few rose petals in your path, you have chosen to see them as just more debris -- if you have elected to see them at all. Wake up and wise up. You need to start acknowledging the gifts as gifts meant for you. You need to understand just how worthy of them you are.http://www.findyourfate.com/rss/dailyhoroscope-feed.asp?sign=Aries [return delivery report]"

    texts = texts.Replace("Free Daily Horoscope by findyourfate.comhttp://www.findyourfate.com", "")

    texts = texts.Replace("http://www.findyourfate.com/rss/dailyhoroscope-feed.asp?sign=Aries [return delivery report]", "")
```

and you will get the same outcome that's of course if you have always

If you wish to use split:

```
Dim arraytext() As String

    arraytext = Split(texts, "Free Daily Horoscope by findyourfate.comhttp://www.findyourfate.com")

    arraytext = Split(arraytext(1), "http://www.findyourfate.com/rss/dailyhoroscope-feed.asp?sign=Aries [return delivery report]")

MsgBox(arraytext(0))
```